# Unable to import fbx files

Tags: import

Having difficulty importing .FBX files into blender.
i select .fbx file and hit import and nothing appears in the editor/scene.
must be a pretty silly question but ive never had this difficulty before.
if anyone has any pointers they would be greatly appreciated.
thank you!

Comment: Could you post this .FBX file?

Comment: http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/apple-iphone-6-3d-model-35596.html

Comment: but it seems to be the same for other files as well including collada and obj :/

Answer (score 2):

.FBX import is fine, just scale of the object is really small.

After import press <kbd>S</kbd> then type 1000.

You can alway check if something is on the scene in *Outliner*.

[image: Outliner]

Comment: Yes, and in the Outliner, there may be nothing at all after an FBX import. With no error message. I had this happen to me today. The only thing which worked reliably for me was the OBJ import. But I've looked at the contents of an OBJ file and it doesn't actually contain a whole lot of information.